# Is there any possible way to get the last value performed in python split function

Tags: python-2.7

For Example,

i have a following txt file in my system

```
My name is pavithran 
I am from chennai
Hobbies are reading
I love cricket
```

In that, I just want to print only the last word of that each file.

My output will be like:

```
pavithran
chennai
reading
cricket
```

I know to perform this, read each line using for loop
and use split function to split the word and print that word you want at certain location

But , i want a last word from each line not on 3rd and 4 th location Like that..How can achieve that?

Comment: `words[-1]`. indexing a list with `-n` prints the n'th elements from the back (starting at 1 this time).

Comment: You should use list `slicing` i.e. `each_line.split()[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Easy

you need to use

```
line.split(" ")[-1]
```

for each line to get the last word

PS comments are not for posting answers